# Posting Long Articles through Admin Panel

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a site with admin panel, through which i can upload images for photo gallery to mysql database etc.

I want to create a page for users which contains many long articles with "Read More" Option on each bottom of article.. for that i tried a column as LONGTEXT in mysql database...For which i used FKeditor to copy paste article contents from doc file / text file.

Can I use other option than LONGTEXT and can upload that doc file / text file through admin panel which will show articles on user page ?

Which options are available for this type of function.

Comment: can you show us what you tried ? -- some code

Comment: yes sure..i will post code i used after few minutes.....

Answer (score 0):

For Posting the long articles the LONGTEXT is fine. In future you can perform search on the article text. Other benefit is it load quickly on the website. If you will upload a text file and save it in the database directly or store the files separately and load them on run time they will make your website slow because the file operations are always slow than loading content from database.

So best solution is use LongTEXT or TEXT and save data using fck editor. Or you can use simple Textarea to store text into database.

Comment: Thanks! been searching for this.